# Where is this scenery (in New Zealand)?

Tags: identify-this, where-on-earth, new-zealand

A friend's family house has this image. They're pretty sure it's a mountain scene in New Zealand.  Best bet currently is Mitre Peak but the lines of the mountain seem reversed...

[image]

Comment: If you take [this photo](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Mitre+Peak/@-44.6269971,167.8387759,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1sAF1QipMxoPATknJx9eEUS-doAv1lYJL5K-EUmAPVCh7i!2e10!3e12!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipMxoPATknJx9eEUS-doAv1lYJL5K-EUmAPVCh7i%3Dw203-h143-k-no!7i1500!8i1061!4m7!3m6!1s0xa9d5e014c0a1252f:0xace0a633a3a2d7c0!8m2!3d-44.6269971!4d167.8387759!10e5!16zL20vMDZwY3d5) of Mitre Peak and invert it horizontally, it will pretty much look the same..

Comment: Extremely [similar photo](https://www.flickr.com/photos/joceykinghorn/11177921176/in/photolist-i2KLwU-RPgzjN-2ojNDUT-7ja6uj-SbLFXf-2nx7KY2-ECyoT2-5JfYJ-2m57kjo-2m4DUjG-dm1dUn-2iKmxTC-yPS3ZR-byZC6v-E88uSQ-GWcdLB-YzMZGG-2obznbV-2n5PPHp-c52uiq-2jbfdBi-btJDtG-o3TDfh-7BDm2o-a2x1XG-NunWjq-3gcnSF-21gi2Co-27famb7-jUpS3X-qSaDzH-27z2DTz-237myC1-6VQDJF-2dzftVN-hAwqJo-ijyZUy-626DdK-bjScRh-7texQ-qeUt8S-2enZTkQ-zxPAVD-FrYYC-nLGFu-bedfgV-2hhbH4m-QFJs9E-dSVaFC-8wi5zS)

Comment: Given that it appears to be a painting, who knows how or why the artist manipulated the scene. Or even if it is based in reality.

Answer (score 3):

Based on a similar painting by [Henry William Kirkwood](https://www.invaluable.com/v2/auction-lot/henry-william-kirkwood-11-c-6cf30e48f2), I'd say this is George Sound in New Zealand:

[image]